# How does astronauts move from point a to b on spacewalks

Tags: iss

How do astronauts move around when on space walks? Do they slowly make their way to their destination while keeping a harness connected to the ISS and changing the connections point as they progress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They carry the SAFER emergency pack for case of falling off the station.

They clip themselves around the station with tethers and connection points.

The Russian segment has a couple of 'cranes' called [Strela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strela_(crane)) that start at the airlocks, and are telescoping poles, to make a shortcut to other modules on the Russian segment.

For larger moves around the rest of the station, there is the CanadArm2 and on the truss itself, there is a cart, that runs on a track along the truss, specifically for this purpose.

Comment: SAFER is for american suits only isn't it ?